# Count amount of people in addresses SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In a table with a primary key of Person_Id and the addresses containing in multiple indexes such as

```
Road_Name, 
House_Number, 
Postcode
```

As some of the addresses are duplicated is it possible to create a unique identifier for each address from the separate indexes using SQL queries?

Then with the unique identifier, find how many People via Person_Ids are at each address?

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result, as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a count of rows for each address, we can use a `GROUP BY` and an aggregate...

```
 SELECT t.addr_road_name 
      , t.addr_house_number
      , t.addr_postal_code
      , COUNT(DISTINCT t.person_id) AS `cnt_persons`
   FROM t
  GROUP
     BY t.addr_road_name 
      , t.addr_house_number
      , t.addr_postal_code
```

If we want to exclude addresses that have a single person, we can add

```
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.person_id) > 1
```

---

For optimal performance with large sets, we want to avoid a "Using filesort" operation by making use of an index that has as leading columns, columns referenced in the `GROUP BY` clause, e.g.

```
 ... ON t (addr_postal_code, addr_house_number, addr_road_name)
```

Comment: I suppose if we are not using a Cross Reference table between Addresses and People we should probably also worry that `Address` to `person_id` could also not be unique in which case one might recommend testing for `DISTINCT person_id` such as `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.person_id) > 1` and `COUNT(DISTINCT t.person_id) AS cnt_persons`

Comment: @Matt: good point. My answer was making an (unwarranted) assumption that `person_id` was a primary (or unique) key of table `t`. Absent a guarantee of uniqueness, the query is counting the *rows* with non-null values of person_id, and the count would include "duplicate" values of `person_id`, and potentially be higher than the result from `COUNT(DISTINCT t.person_id)`.